Telegram Bot : aiogram Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
Im sure running bot 1 time and closed other
but when bot start and user request to bot . bot start error
i tried change Api / bot token and everything but nothing change
Anyone know problem ?
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher:Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates

TOKEN='...'

async def on_handle_terminate(update, error):
    print('Hadnle terminate, Stopping bot...')

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.register_errors_handler(callback=on_handle_terminate,
                           exception=TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates)

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())



